# How to assign multiple event IDs per column in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, random

I am newbie to R and learning Introduction to R. I have a large matrix (multiples of 100000s) and a few hundred columns. I am giving an example matrix herebelow.

```
set.seed(1)
m4 <- matrix(sample(0:3,5*4, replace=TRUE),5,4) # sample event matrix
m4GROUP <- data.frame( X1=rowSums(m4[,1, drop=FALSE]), X2=rowSums(m4[,2:3]), 
                       X3=rowSums(m4[,4, drop=FALSE]) ) # 1 column
m4GroupColID <- colSums(m4GROUP) # coln sum to generate a matrix per col
```

Output

```
m4
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    0    1
[2,]    1    3    0    2
[3,]    2    2    2    3
[4,]    3    2    1    1
[5,]    0    0    3    3

> m4GROUP # group by Col 1, Cols 2-3, Col4
  X1 X2 X3
1  1  3  1
2  1  3  2
3  2  4  3
4  3  3  1
5  0  3  3

> m4GroupColID
X1 X2 X3 
 7 16 10
```

- I need to generate a matrix of 5 x 4 x total eventsIDs per Row by 
  Group.  In this case, I need to get 4 matrix for 4 cols with a 
  dimension of 5 x max(M4Group) per column.
- For Every Row, the IDs are replaced (i.e. same IDs can repeat, if we 
  have a grouping of two or more columns, between columns    forming
  the  group)
- Between Row, the IDs are not replaced (i.e IDs of previous Row can 
  not be allocated for the next row in the same group having two or 
  more columns); however, IDs of the current row can be allocated between columns in the group.
- Finally, for groups formed by more than one column, the totalIDs per
  row can be randomly allocated. This ensures, the group having more
  than one column are impacted by the ID.

**I'm sorry this is a long post and I just do not know how to shorten this without losing the essence.**

Total event IDs are 7 for col 1, 16 for cols 2-3 and 10 for col.4:

The final outputs, for example with a random allocation in cols 2-3, per column are as follows: IDs for cols are: 1-7, 8-23, 24-33.

```
Col 1    Col 2        Col 3        col 4
1 0 0    8 9 10 0     0 0 0 0      24 0 0 
2 0 0    11 12 13 0   0 0 0 0      25 26 0
3 4 0    14 15 17 0   14 16 0 0    27 28 29
5 6 7    18 20 0 0    18 0 0 0     30 0 0 
0 0 0    0 0 0 0      21 22 23 0   31 32 33
```

If we have just one event per row, the id generation and distribution are fairly straightforward.

```
m1 <- matrix(sample(0:1,5*4, replace=TRUE),5,4) # sample event matrix
ifelse(m1==0, 0, matrix(sample(1:1,5*4, replace = T), 5,4)) # works for one  ID assignment
```

I started with a loop, with a knowledge, for loops are not faster in R. But,I am getting errors, irrespective of with or without replacement. I definitely need (Replacement = True on the same row) and (Replacement = False) between Rows.

```
nc <- max(m4GROUP$X1)
i <- 1
j <- 1
while(i <- 5){
  if(m4[i,j] == 0){
    m[i,j] <- matrix(0, 5, nc)
  } else {
    if(m4[i,j] == 1){
      m[i,j] <- matrix(sample(1, i*nc, replace=T), 5, nc)
    } else {
      m[i,j] <- matrix(sample(2, i*nc, replace=T), 5, nc)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm aware it is not correct. I get the following errors.

```
Error in m[i, j] <- matrix(sample(0, i * nc, replace = T), 5, nc) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
Error in m[i, j] <- matrix(0, 5, nc) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I also tried the following: I do not get results that satisfy the above bullet points; further, they are starting with the same ID for every row. I get only 3 rows and not 4 rows. Finally, this is not ideal, considering my actual sample size.

```
size <- c(1:7, 1:16, 1:9, 10)
startID <- which(size==1)
endIDs <- c(which(size==1)[-1] -1, length(size))
mats <- mapply(function(x, y) t(size[seq(x, y)]), startID, endIDs)
library(plyr)
m <- (rbind.fill.matrix(mats))
```

output:

```
m
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
[1,] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[2,] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
[3,] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7  8  9 10 NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

I am once again sorry for the long post but thanks for not only reading this, but also also the help.

Comment: Not making a lot of sense to me. How can a colSum result be an "ID"? ... and you should not refer to things as "ids". When you are really referring to an object, use the "name" whatever it might be. Matrices only have 2 dimensions. You need to allocate an `array`.

Comment: thanks. the example scenario is like an event processing, where values contained in every element is an event or events. Every event gets an event ID. In this example, x1, x2 & x3 and x4 are groups and hence I need to generate a "number sequence" or an "id" per event per column (x). Since we can have only 2 dimension in a matrix, you get a matrix per x, where r=number of rows, c=events. In the case of x1 matrix, r=5, c=3.

Comment: my current thinking to the solution is as follows: (1) construct matrix of "0s", say for an example: 5 x 3 (max event shown for x1 in m4Group). (2) get a vector of serial numbers (1-7), and (3) setup a condition to replace the "0s" with elements shown by m4Group per group.  I am not sure if this is the correct and an efficient approach

Comment: It's generally less effective in requesting a solution to describe your unsuccessful efforts in psuedo-code than it is to describe the problem carefully in English.

Comment: Just describing the problem without showing efforts can be a dangerous. I believe I have done both. Thanks foryour comments though. :)